# In the following Java code, what is the advantage of using the Apache FileUtils class?

Tags: java, file-io, apache-commons

I came across the following Java code snippet ( [source](http://www.studytrails.com/java-io/url-reading-tailing-reverse-reading.jsp) ), that is used to read the *last* line in a file. It uses two Apache libraries - [ReversedLinesFileReader](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html) and [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).  Here it is :

```
ReversedLinesFileReader reader = new ReversedLinesFileReader(FileUtils.getFile(file));
String s = "";
while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

What I don't understand however, is why do we not simply put in a file path for the argument to ReversedLinesFileReader , and instead we use the FileUtils class.

Why Can't I simply say instead:

```
File someFile = new File("someFile.txt");
ReversedLinesFileReader reader = new ReversedLinesFileReader(  someFile ) ;
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... what is the advantage of using the Apache FileUtils class?

If `file` is just one string, there is no advantage.  The call to `getFile` is going to call `new File(file)` ... after messing around to cope with the "var-args-ness" of the `file` parameter.  So in fact, there is a *performance penalty* for using `getFile` in this case, for zero concrete<sup>1</sup> benefit.

If `file` is a `String[]`, then `FileUtils.getFile(file)` turns the strings into a file path.

---

> Why Can't I simply say instead ...

Assuming that `file` is a `String`, you can, and (IMO) you should do what you proposed.

---

<sup>1 - I have seen people argue in cases like this that it is an advantage to avoid using the `java.io` classes directly, but frankly I don't buy it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using File is fine. ReversedLinesFileReader has a constructor that accepts a File as an input.

The reason you would use FileUtils is if you could benefit from what the FileUtils.getFile() overloaded methods offer, like passing a String[] of path elements, etc.

Other than that, no difference.

Comment: Strictly, it is not overloading ... and you are paying a varargs performance penalty in this case.  The JVM has to create and initialize a temporary array to hold the single `String` argument.

Comment: It is overloaded. FileUtils provides 2 versions of the FileUtils.getFile() method with different parameters. As stated in my comment java.io.File is a fine choice. I meant that if you were already given the file path in a format not accepted by java.util.File constructor, maybe then you would find it useful to use FileUtils if it provided a getFile() method that accepted what you already had.

Comment: I see what you are saying.